# Moment of Intertia of hemisphere

Tags: classical-mechanics, moment-problem

Calculate the moment of inertia of a solid uniform hemisphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$; $z \geq 0$ with mass $m$ about the $z$ – axis.

My attempt: We know that MI of a solid hemisphere is $2Ma^2/5$ where $M$ is mass and a is radius of solid hemisphere. And the MI of a solid hemisphere is $Ma^2/5$. So in above question mass is given $m$ and radius is a so  $MI$ of hemisphere is $2ma^2/5$. Is this correct answer ? Answer given is $15mπa/32$.

Comment: MI has dimensions mass $\times$ length$^2$ so "Answer given" is wrong.

Comment: Your answer is correct. And the "given answer" is not.

Comment: @KeithMcClary thanx

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the mass is m and the radius a, you do not need to integrate in order to find out the MI of a solid hemisphere.

$$MI_{sphere}=\frac{2Ma^2}{5}$$

In the process of making a hemisphere out of it we know that we are eliminating mass symmetrically from the axis, i.e.

$$MI_{cut out}=MI_{hemisphere\ left\ out}$$

and their sum is $\frac{2Ma^2}{5}$.

Thus $$MI_{hemisphere}=\frac{Ma^2}{5}$$.

But remember that M is not the mass of your hemisphere.

$$M=2m$$ where m is the mass of your hemisphere and M that of whole sphere.

Thus $$MI_{hemisphere}=\frac{2ma^2}{5}$$